# How to query with orWhereMonth in laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel

How can I convert this into laravel query builder?

```
select *, (col1 + col2 + col3) as total where (MONTH('date_') = '01' OR MONTH('date_') = '02') AND YEAR('date_') = '2019' AND paid = 1
```

I tried this but I think it is not returning correctly.

```
$carDataAm = DB::table('carwash')
                 ->selectRaw('*, (col1 + col2 + col3) as totalAmount')
                 ->where('paid','1')
                 ->whereMonth('date_', '=', '01')
                 ->orWhereMonth('date_', '=', '02')
                 ->whereYear('date_', '=', '2019')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: and why do you think it isn't returning corectly? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence of grouping expressions together in Eloquent (like you grouped `(MONTH('date_') = '01' OR MONTH('date_') = '02')` in SQL using brackets `()`) is to use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping) (thanks to @lagbox for the link) like this:

```
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('date_', '=', '01')
         ->orWhereMonth('date_', '=', '02');
})
```

Comment: got the idea with this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping)  as @lagbox suggested.

```
DB::table('carwash')
                 ->selectRaw('*, (col1 + col2 + col3) as totalAmount')
                 ->where('paid','1')
                 ->where(function($query){
                    ->whereMonth('date_', '=', '01')
                    ->orWhereMonth('date_', '=', '02')
})
                 ->whereYear('date_', '=', '2019')
                 ->get();
```

Otherwise whenever your orWhere condition matches it will fetch those data also not regarding other where conditions.